# Inserting a link for a .png file in R Markdown

Tags: r, plot, hyperlink, markdown, png

My instructor is showing me in R Markdown how to create a link in using a .png file. Her code is not working. Also, I've added the "*" to create a bullet list which is not working.

---

### title: "R Markdown Intro"
author: "Maddie"
date: "2023-07-20"
output: html_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

### R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring:
*HTML
*PDF
*MS Word documents.

For more details on using R Markdown click here[link](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com).

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```
summary(cars)
```

### Including Plots

You may also embed plots, for example: (Plot this way code is not working)

[image: Plot this way]

Errors:

(No image at path https://pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/13/52/arrow-147464_340.png)
Error: unexpected '[' in "!["

Things I have tried are, using Bard, tried creating my own .png file and link, sourced internet for another .png link.

Comment: When I go to your link https://pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/13/52/arrow-147464_340.png my browser gets Error 404, Page Not Found. So I agree with R, there is no image at that path. Fix your link to point to an image.

Comment: You don't need to do an external link, it can also be a path to a file on your computer.

Comment: Thanks Gregor for your support! I had tried the external link, but R Markdown was not accepting the path. I tried numerous syntax edits and FINALLY got it to work using another file! ![Plot this way](https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/07/21/18/01/chrysanthemum-8142073_1280.jpg) I appreciate your suggestions! Danielle